# Javascript, iFrame - how do cross browser, get the value from text box in another script?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

The following code works on IE6+

```
thisMessagePreFormat = document.getElementById('child').contentWindow
           .window.document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML;
```

I've googled and tried various things...

```
alert(window.frames['child'].document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML);
alert(document.frames('child').window.document
           .getElementById('childcont').innerHTML);
alert(document.frames('child').document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML);
alert(document.getElementById('child').contentWindow.window
           .document.getElementById('childcont').body.innerHTML);
```

However I can't access the value from the child script. I know this would normally be a security risk, but in this case it isn't a problem.

EDIT:

```
<html><head></head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function receive() {
        alert(document.getElementById('child').contentWindow.document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML);
        alert('Send Message');
        alert('EE ' + document.getElementById('child').contentWindow.document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML);
        alert('US ' + document.getElementById('child').contentWindow.window.document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML);
        alert('ME ' + document.getElementById('child').contentWindow.document.getElementById('childcont').valueOf);
        alert('EE ' + document.getElementById('child').contentWindow.document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML);
        //alert('US ' + document.getElementById('child').contentWindow.window.document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML);
    }
</script>

<iframe  id="child" name="child" src="window/bottom.html" ></iframe>

<table style="CURSOR: pointer; display: inline;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" onClick="javascript:receive();">
    <tr><td height="17"><nobr>&nbsp;Send&nbsp;</nobr></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

On window/bottom.html I have...

```
<html><head></head>
<body topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid gray;">
    <tr><td>
            <textarea id="childcont"></textarea>
    </td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've try to get the value typed into the childcont textbox in my parent script.

Comment: What do you want its a little unclear?

Comment: "I know this would normally be a security risk, but in this case it isn't a problem." What does that mean? If it is cross domain, it is not going to work.

Comment: What are your errors? Is the frame fully loaded before you try to get the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong direction.

Change `.innerHTML` to `.value`:

```
alert(window.frames['child'].document.getElementById('childcont').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried with

```
 document.getElementById('child').contentWindow.document.getElementById('childcont').innerHTML;
```

in FF and it works fine. while it is not cross-domain it should work

your error on the fourth alert try is: contentWindow is the window of the iframe, it doesn't have a window property. also, #childcont won't have a body, as it is an element, not a document